# Regex: include some characters but not others

Tags: regex, vba

For the string abc-1234_56678-123_6y1, I want to only extract the trailing _6yz.

I need the selection to

1. start with an "_"
2. include at least one letter
3. not include a "-"
   Every attempt I have made returns "_56678-123_6y1". Here's what I was the most confident in
   _.*[\p{L}].*([^-])
   where I search for substrings that do not contain a "-".

What am I missing?

Comment: How about `_[^-]+$`?

Answer (score 1):

I was at this problem longer than I'd like to admit, then stumbled on to the answer while doing another query. The final answer for my problem is

```
_[^-]+([\p{L}].*)
```

Henry Woody's answer is also good aside from the condition that my selection must contain a letter.